# Command to set block based on item presence

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to figure out how to get this command

```
execute if entity @p[distance=.11,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"key\",\"color\":\"white\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"}}}}] run setblock -191 21 -52 minecraft:redstone_block
```

to work with an arrow renamed as "key" and then it in theory should open a Iron door that is nearby, just by being near it. However anytime I get close to the Iron door, nothing seems to change. I also have this command

```
execute unless entity @p[distance=.11,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"key\",\"color\":\"white\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"}}}}] run setblock -191 21 -52 minecraft:stone_bricks
```

for when someone is near the area but without the item. That seems to work fine.

Can someone explain this to me? I am very confused in how to get it to work.

I'm using Minecraft 1.14.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your commands, instead of .11 you need to put ..11 for it to work. Also ensure you are running this in a Repeat Command Block set to Always Active.

Correct First Command:

`execute if entity @p[distance=..11,nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"key\",\"color\":\"white\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"}}}}] run setblock -191 21 -52 minecraft:redstone_block`

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Invalid is this answer helped you, then please accept it.